# Argument of type 'typeof UsersC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'

Tags: typescript

TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof UsersC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.   Type 'typeof UsersC' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.     Types of property 'contextType' are incompatible.       Type 'React.Context | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").Context | undefined'.         Type 'React.Context' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").Context'.           The types of 'Provider.propTypes' are incompatible between these types.             Type 'React.WeakValidationMap<React.ProviderProps> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").WeakValidationMap<import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ProviderProps> | undefined'.               Type 'React.WeakValidationMap<React.ProviderProps>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").WeakValidationMap<import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ProviderProps>'.                 Types of property 'children' are incompatible.                   Type 'React.Validator<React.ReactNode> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").Validator<import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode> | undefined'.                     Type 'React.Validator<React.ReactNode>' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index").Validator<import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode>'.                       Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/It-kamasutra/social-network/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode'.                         Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.                           Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props

I tried to import a class component, but I'm getting an error that I've been struggling to fix for an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update type definitions : If you are using external libraries with type definitions, such as @types/react-redux, make sure that they are up to date. Sometimes, outdated type definitions can cause compatibility issues.

Comment: I have everything of the same version